# Optimize aggregate in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using the following aggregate query to group lesson weekly. But this is taking 1.7s execution time. Is there any way to minimize the execution time and optimize this ?

```
let unsorted = await Lesson.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              _id: {
                $in: result.lessons,
              },
              type: req.params.type,
            },
          },
          {
            $sort: {
              createdAt: 1,
            },
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: "$week", //$week is the column name in collection
              count: {
                $sum: 1,
              },
              obj: {
                //creates object
                $push: {
                  _id: "$_id",
                  //push required values from model
                  lessonTitle: "$lessonTitle",
                  lessonSlug: "$lessonSlug",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        ]);

        let lessons = unsorted.map((lesson) => ({
          week: parseInt(lesson._id),
          lessons: lesson.obj,
        }));
```

expected results:
[Expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsRbY.png)

Comment: It depends on multiple param. How many mode cluster. Are you not using pagination. How many indices you have. Whether query uses index. And many more.

Comment: I don't see any reason for the `{ $sort: { createdAt: 1 } }` stage. You don't use operators like `$first`, `$last`, where the order matters. If you like to sort the result the run sort at the end.

Comment: Please don't paste links to images, use formatted test instead, see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)